# Building objects while passing them as const reference C++

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, constants

Can I build parameter const reference inside the method call?
I know it compiles, but am not completely confident it is correct at run time.

I have the following classes:

```
class A{
public:
void doThings(const B& b);
}

class B{
   B(int i, int j);

}


int main{

    A a;

    a.doThings(B(1,2));   //Is this OK?

}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be wrong?

Comment: Your code definitely does not compile.

Comment: Yes, you can use a const reference to a temporary object inside a method/function, but you cannot store a pointer to it or use it in another thread, and the compiler does not protect you against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *concept* is fine... a temporary `B` will be constructed and passed by reference. Don't store that reference in `A` or use anywhere beyond the scope of `doThings`.

But your code is no good. Here, I fixed it for you:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
  void doThings(const B& b) {}
};

class B {
public:
  B(int i, int j) {}
};


int main() {

  A a;

  a.doThings(B(1, 2));   //Is this OK?

}
```